# Share reactive form between components

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-reactive-forms

I need to build two screens, the first one with two inputs for phone number and email and below the address of the user with the option to click to edit. If the user clicks on the edit button he will be redirected to another page(component) to edit the informations and save to update the information on the first screen. I'm thinking of creating only one form with the user information and address, but I don't know the best way to share the controls with a second component. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7oswy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Angular v13

I tried using view child but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is likely to get closed because it's opinion-based.

However, all you probably need to do is create a component for your form. You can control which fields are in the form via inputs or other mechanisms like state.

If you need to store data from the form for use elsewhere, create a service to hold the data as a property/Subject/BehaviorSubject according to your needs that can be injected into whatever components need the data.

Comment: The problem is that I will not use the "address-form-component" directly in the "main" component. It will only be redirected,so I can't use a "prop"

Comment: You're going to have to provide some sample code to explain your workflow or all anyone can really do is speculate

Comment: It's in the link I provided, unfortunately I can't put the actual code but the problem is what I described...use a form of the component "app.component" in the "hello.component", both components exist in the sample code I provided

Comment: I still see the same solution - a form component that has some fields enabled/disabled based on which route you're on, with the form's data persisted in a Subject on a service.